# Why can I reference a non-existing function within another function?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here, I will show that referencing a non-existing function from another function is possible and SQL Server doesn't check it until the execution time:

```
USE [SomeDataBase];
SELECT dbo.Booo();
```

Obviously, if you don't have function `Booo` then an error will be generated regarding function `Booo` is not recognized. This isn't a surprise though!

Now, try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Foo()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Temp INT
    SET @Temp = (SELECT dbo.Booo())
    RETURN 1
END
```

Surprisingly, this scrip creates the function `Foo` despite the fact that the `Booo` function doesn't exit.

Any idea?

Comment: That's standard, documented SQL Server behavior. It's a **feature** - not a bug.

Comment: @marc_s: Any reference?

Comment: See [Deferred Name Resolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686.aspx) - this applies to both functions and procedures

Comment: @marc_s: Thank you so much. I vote for your response for the answer. But don't you think it is a bad idea and can risk the reliability of DB? Also I tried this problem in Oracle 11g and it prevented the script: somehow "eager resolution".

Answer (score 5):

Why do you think that's a bug? Since the code isn't actually *executed* until you run the `Foo` function, there's a case to be made that *that* is the point where the check should be made.

Maybe you write your functions in a top-down manner, rather than a bottom-up manner, and you want to write the upper levels first, drilling down to specifics later.

Unless it's documented to work one way and it works another way, it's not a bug, just a disagreement between you and Microsoft :-)

Comment: First of all I don't think we can keep using only and only one design strategy in the application life cycle, sometimes we are on up-down sometimes bottom-up. Moreover database refactoring matters. Anyway, I think marc_a comment and reference is very enlightening

Comment: @Alireza, I'm not stating you should use only one strategy. In fact, the function having to exist would limit you to bottom up. If you want to use top-down, you need to be able to create things that reference non-existent items (that you haven't yet defined). In any case, it's still only a _bug_ if you can find doco that says it's not allowed.

Comment: True, now I get you. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you do

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Foo()
RETURNS INT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Temp INT
    SET @Temp = (SELECT dbo.Booo())
    RETURN 1
END
```

You get your desired error and the function is not created. That does make altering the definition of `dbo.Booo` in the future more painful however (need to drop `dbo.Foo` first).

You can also use a [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/tools.aspx) project to validate things like referencing non existent objects/columns without using schemabinding.